# AS3.0 Loopback H264 Flv by appendBytes is not smooth

Tags: h.264, flash, flv

I use Data Generation Mode to loopback a H264 flv real-time vide,the video data is collected from webrtc and pushed immediatly to flash player.
I set buffer time=0, and I am sure there is no "buffer empty" during this Time,but it always freeze for a while when the camera move fast.
but if  I set buffer time=3, it play smoothly.

Any one can help me, thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you want a buffer time? Videos cannot be played smoothly without buffering, Videos don't "load" at a consistent rate, as you've seen with, say, youtube videos.

Comment: Actually,I was playing a real time video,so the I can't set a buffer time